# How to ignore an entity field in Spring Data Cassandra?

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

How do I ignore an entity field in Spring Data Cassandra? Using the `javax.persistence.Transient` annotation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Try annotating your transient fields with `org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient` and report back whether that works.

So, I wrote a test adding three fields:

```
@javax.persistence.Transient
private Boolean one;
@org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient
private Boolean two;
private Boolean three;
```

to an entity to Cassandra. Result:

- `one` was populated.
- `two` was *not* populated.
- `three` was populated. (just a check that I got my changes through)

Conclusion:

- `javax.persistence.Transient` will *not* ignore a field.
- **`org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient` will ignore a field.**

> If it does, you get bonus points for creating a test for it and sending a pull request!

Sorry, I'm on a tight schedule and don't know the code well enough. Created a [JIRA ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-189), though!

Comment: One caveat: you cannot put this on a `@PrimaryKeyColumn` field or Spring will throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recall explicitly coding this into spring-data-cassandra, but that behavior might just be provided entirely by spring-data-commons.  I don't have time right now to create a test for that, though.

Try annotating your transient fields with `org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient` and report back whether that works.  If it does, you get bonus points for creating a test for it and sending a pull request!  :)